# Conditional navigation on a column by generic inquire in acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I create a generic inquire in Acumatica ERP. Do we have any way to navigate on two different screen by clicking on a same column on the basis of the value of other column value, like  conditional navigation apply on a column value